# Clojure loop through a vector starting from the nth element not 0

Tags: clojure

I would like to loop through a vector starting from the nth element not 0;

How it looks like in Java:

```
for(int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
    newText += contents[i] + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `drop` function to skip first `n` elements and then loop over the result. For example, if you want to skip two first elements:

```
user=> (drop 2 [1 2 3 4])
(3 4)
```

The following can possibly do the same that the Java form you provided:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
(str/join " " (drop first-index contents))
```

Comment: `subvec` may be an option if you know the element count but I don't know which one is more efficient.

Comment: @FrankC. if the starting index is large, then `subvec` will definitely be more efficient.  `drop` is `O(n)` w.r.t. the drop-count, which `subvec` is always `O(1)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are always dealing with a vector, then `subvec` is a good choice.  For example:

```
(subvec contents firstIndex)
```

If you want to be compatible with sequences in general, you'll want to use `drop`.  `drop` is `O(n)` w.r.t. the number of elements dropped, which `subvec` is always `O(1)`.  If you're only ever dropping a few elements, the difference is negligible.  But for dropping a large number of elements (i.e., large `firstIndex`), `subvec` will be a clear winner.  But `subvec` is only available on vectors.